# What's the idiomatic way of getting the version of the Ruby interpreter?

Tags: ruby

In a Ruby script, what's the idiomatic way of getting the interpreter's version as of Ruby 1.9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  **RUBY_VERSION** constant to get the version number

Comment: Pardon my overly-strong typing, but `1.9.1` isn't a number.